# What's new in fluent nhibernate 1.4

Tags: .net, orm, fluent-nhibernate

FluentNhibernate 1.4 was released in December: http://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentNhibernate

I have searched the interned, but cannot find any release notes about it. Anybody knows what's new in this version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn´t seem to be a real changelog, but a short announcement on google groups by the latest contributor states it´s a bugfix release only with no new features.

Answer (score 1):

The FluentNHibernate 1.4.0 changelog/release notes are on GitHub:

https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/releases/tag/1.4.0.1